# How to disable collapsing in a grouped grid in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Everything's in the subject. I have a grouped grid, like [this Sencha example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/groupgrid.html). I would like to remove the [+][-] signs in order to disable collapsing.

I thought there would be some config for the grouping feature, something like 'collapsible: false', but there is not any.

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 3):

Use configuration to disable collapse config property. From Sencha:

> collapsible : Boolean
>
> Set to false to disable collapsing groups from the UI.
>
> This is set to false when the associated store is buffered.
>
> Defaults to: true

*Source: [Sencha Documentation of the `collapsible` configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-cfg-collapsible).*

Comment: Please provide a short summary of the linked page for future reference.

Comment: This is the best answer, as it doesn't override a private Ext JS method as other answers on this question do.

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit Ext.grid.feature.Grouping and redefine onGroupClick method. It's not good but the simplest way for now:

```
Ext.define( 'My.grid.feature.RightsGrouping', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',

   onGroupClick: function(view, group, idx, foo, e) {
   }
});
```

Also you'll have to edit CSS to remove collapse sign and change cursor pointer:

```
  .x-grid-group-hd .x-grid-cell-inner { cursor: default; }
  .x-grid-group-title { background-image: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Very nice Serg, thanks.

even easier for the override is:

```
... 
features: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',{ 
        onGroupClick: function() {} /* do nothing! */ 
    })
]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This was not working in 4.2.1.

Figured out a solution seemed very funny to me

```
...
groupcollapse: 
{
         fn: me.onGroupingGroupcollapse,
         scope: me
}
...
...

onGroupingGroupcollapse: function(view, node, group, eOpts) 
{
        Ext.getCmp('gridCenters').view.features[0].expand(node.name,true);
}
...
```